# How to program a command application in visual studio to read a batch file

Tags: c#, batch-file, command

I'm creating my first command application in Visual Studio.

I was wondering what is the command to read lines from a batch file. I need to be able to read the first line of a batch file then call some method with the parameters I got from the first line, after that I need to be able to read the second line from a batch file and call the same method, and so forth until the end of the file.

I already know how to call methods. I just need to know how to read the batch file.

Comment: Do you really want to read a batch file? Or do you want the parameters passed into your program from the batch file calling it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using(StreamReader batchReader = new StreamReader("path to batch file"))
{
    string batchCommand;
    while(!batchReader.EndOfStream)
    {
        batchCommand = batchReader.ReadLine();
        // do your processing with batch command
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A batch file is a text file, so you can do:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
```

Or if you want to read lazily (available in .net 4):

```
IEnumerable<string> lines=File.ReadLines(filename);
```

But since batch files are typically rather small, I'd most likely use `ReadAllLines`.

---

If you want the command line arguments passed to your application you get them using `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs`